# CSS z-index help in IE

Tags: css, z-index, drop-down-menu

I have a little problem that I cant solve.

I made a dropdown menu, and its OK but in Chrome I can only see the hover effect on the child elements, and can on the parents.

In FF and IE its OK only Chrome is the bad one, could someone give me a hint?

```
nav.main_menu {
            position: relative;
            top: 29px;
            left: 220px;
            bottom: 1px;
            height: 90px;
            width: 680px;
            z-index: 3000;
        }

div#container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 38px 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

It's OK in any other browsers but not in IE

Comment: Show your markup too - hard to tell what's going on just from css rules.

Comment: yes you better show you markup.but i think the only problem here is the position of nav.main_menu it should be absolute..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CSS reset sheet. I find that solves some of my cross browser issues.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

(you should really show your markup)